Distorted PBF Vector Tiles in OpenLayers
I have a local set of PBF files that render parks and roads in a geographic area. The parks display correctly, but the roads are completely distorted at all zoom levels - what could be causing this distortion and how it can be fixed?

The tiles came from geofrabik.de via a single osm.pbf file, converted to MBTiles, and then uploaded to QGIS and exported as XYZ vector tiles (PBF format) with the '3857' projection. I've tried exporting the road tiles on their own, with and without an extent, with and without its specified min and max zoom levels, setting projections to and from '3857' and '4326', adding a tileGrid/tilePixelRatio setting, converting the MBTiles to PBF files without QGIS (and unzipping them) but nothing has corrected the issue so far. The original MBTiles display correctly with Tileserver.
Here is the chunk of code I'm using to create the Vector Tile Layer. I cannot recreate the map in a sandbox because the vector tiles are made from tens of thousands of files:
import VectorTileLayer from 'ol/layer/VectorTile';
import VectorTileSource from 'ol/source/VectorTile';
import MVT from 'ol/format/MVT.js';
import {createXYZ, TileGrid} from 'ol/tilegrid';

const vectorTile_PBF = new VectorTileLayer({
  source: new VectorTileSource({
    minZoom: 4,
    maxZoom: 14,
    format: new MVT({
      //tileGrid: createXYZ({tileSize: 512, minZoom: 4, maxZoom: 14}),
      //tilePixelRatio: 8,
    }),
    url: './Vector_Tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf',
    renderMode: 'vector',
  }),
  className: "basemap-PBF",
});

